# Android Recyclerview for a few items

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-recyclerview

I have a list CardViews, each of which has a title and an icon. Upon clicking on each item, an Activity opens with that certain card's details.
I don't think I need more than a few items (I don't think more than 10), and I'm not sure how dynamic and changing they will be.

My question is: Should I use a `RecyclerView` to show these items, or should I just duplicate the cards and show them inside a `LinearLayout` without a `RecyclerView`?

In terms of performance, which option is better?

Comment: Why you are thinking about  LinearLayout ? . you should use RecyclerView. It's better idea .

Comment: @Himani Why is it better in my case? Please explain.

Comment: RecyclerView have it's own advantage and in small phone screen it's easier to scroll .

Comment: @Himani What advantage in my case? And what's the difference if I put my layout in a NestedScrollView?

Comment: You can do the same in RecyclerView RecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);

Comment: @Himani Ok, thanks. Although, is there a disadvantage to using a plain LinearLayout in my case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both options should be OK (I haven't tested the performance, but both run OK), although I would prefer the `Linearlayout`. Because the list is small, you lose most advantages of the `RecyclerView` (performance-wise).

If you decide to go with the `LinearLayout`, you could create a [Compound control](https://www.google.cz/search?q=android%20compound%20control) and reuse it for the different items so you don't have to edit every item manually if something changes.

And if you would decide to use the RecyclerView, don't forget to call `setItemViewCacheSize()` and set it to a reasonable amount (the count of your items), because for so few items it doesn't make sense to need to re-populate the items every time you scroll. It makes sense for bigger lists, where you can't effectively work with that many items, but for cca 10 items it seems faster if you cache them all. The next thing you should also do is call `setHasFixedSize(true)` on the RecyclerView. And if you don't need nested scrolling, call `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` too, otherwise the scrolling might behave a bit strange (no "fast/continued scrolling" if you swipe quickly).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I chose to go with a RecyclerView in the end, and implemented your tips. Do you think a RecyclerView might be causing long loading time for the app? If so, is there a way to make it better in that way?

Comment: @amitairos You 're welcome. I was just dealing with the same problem and I am glad I could help. If you don't notice any extremely long loading times it should be perfectly fine. After all it is meant to be working even with thousands of items in the RecyclerView.